How to update a value of a UiState on a StateFlow?
Having this on my viewmodel:
val uiState: StateFlow<BusStopsDBScreenUiState> = busDataRepository.getBusStops()
        .map<List<BusStop>, BusStopsDBScreenUiState> { busStops ->
            BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Success(busStops, Res.string.bus_stops_db_filled)
        }
        .catch { throwable ->
            emit(BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Error(throwable))
        }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Loading)

    fun updateBusStops() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                busDataRepository.updateBusStops()
            }
        }
    }

With this UiState:
sealed interface BusStopsDBScreenUiState {
    object Loading : BusStopsDBScreenUiState
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : BusStopsDBScreenUiState
    data class Success(
        val data: List<BusStop>,
        val dialogText: StringResource?
    ) : BusStopsDBScreenUiState
}

I need to implement a method on my viewmodel that modifies the dialogText variable from
my Sucess uistate to null, for hidding the dialog when the user press the dialog close button:
fun closeDialog() {
    //TODO
}

How can I modify my val uiState: StateFlow<BusStopsDBScreenUiState> in that new function to set the success dialogText variable to null without lossing the data variable content?

SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000) will reset dialogText to Res.string.bus_stops_db_filled if you go to next screen and come back after 5 secs. Is it expected behavior?

That can be done by introducing an additional MutableStateFlow:
private val showDialog = MutableStateFlow(true)

Now your uiState needs to be derived from two flows. You can combine them like this:
val uiState: StateFlow<BusStopsDBScreenUiState> = combine(
    showDialog,
    busDataRepository.getBusStops(),
) { showDialog, busStops ->
    BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Success(
        data = busStops,
        dialogText = if (showDialog) Res.string.bus_stops_db_filled else null,
    ) as BusStopsDBScreenUiState
}
    .catch { throwable ->
        emit(BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Error(throwable))
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Loading,
    )

Instead of map this uses the combine's transform block where you now have the values of both flows available. This allows you to set dialogText accordingly.
You can now simply toggle the MutableStateFlow's value to hide the dialog:
fun closeDialog() {
    showDialog.value = false
}

When this is called, only the combine's transform block will be executed again (and everything after that), the busDataRepository.getBusStops() flow didn't change so its old value is used. You now have a new BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Success value in your StateFlow with the same data but dialogText set to null.

You might want to consider extracting the mapping logic into a separate function to keep the uiState property clean of business logic:
private fun BusStopsDBScreenUiState(
    showDialog: Boolean,
    busStops: List<BusStop>,
): BusStopsDBScreenUiState = BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Success(
    data = busStops,
    dialogText = if (showDialog) Res.string.bus_stops_db_filled else null,
)

Then you can even convert the function call in the lambda to a reference, which makes it even more concise:
val uiState: StateFlow<BusStopsDBScreenUiState> =
    combine(
        showDialog,
        busDataRepository.getBusStops(),
        ::BusStopsDBScreenUiState,
    ).catch { throwable ->
        emit(BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Error(throwable))
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = BusStopsDBScreenUiState.Loading,
    )


your answer seems to be super complex, like killing flies with tanks, maybe is a simpler way to simply modify the value to null as I requested in my question? or is not possible?

MutableStateFlow is comparatively light-weight, but since it still behaves as a flow it can be integrated into your flow chain. There is not really another option when you want to let your flows automatically handle the UI udates.

I mean achieving this without using combine and a new variable called showDialog , simply changing the variable inside the success state i showed in the question to null

You need to somehow trigger a re-execution of the mapping logic. If you would only use a simple Boolean instead of the MutableStateFlow<Boolean> you wouldn't need combine, but it also wouldn't trigger a new flow value. Only when the mapping logic would be re-executed due to some other updates (in this case the repo flow) the newly emitted value would have dialogText = null. There is no way around, you somehow have to hook into the flow chain, and MutableStateFlow is the easiest way. I updated the answer with a small refactoring, maybe that makes it feel more clean.

really your answer seems to be super complex for me, sorry. I don't understand it. StateFlows are very complex for me. It's not your fault. Also, how can you show the dialog when the data is received from the room database? it should be done automatically.

You already used StateFlow in your question, I just added a little bit to it. It's basically the same, only that the mapping logic now includes the values of two flows and not just one. As to how to show the dialog: You can just test for dialogText != null. -- Do you have issues getting this to work or do you just don't understand why and how it works?

Another solution if you don't want to combine multiple flows is to create a view model state which is separate to your UI state. The view model state could look something like this:
data class ViewModelState(
    val busStops: List<BusStop> = emptyList(),
    val dialogText: StringResource = null,
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val throwable: Throwable? = null,
)

You would then have your mutable state flow be of the type MutableStateFlow<ViewModelState> and make use of the map and stateIn functions to convert this to a StateFlow<BusStopsDBScreenUiState>. This would allow you to individually modify parts of your state without relying on the mapping from your repository result.
E.g.
fun ViewModelState.toUiState() = when {
    isLoading == true -> Loading
    throwable != null -> Error(throwable)
    else -> Success(data = busStops, dialogText = dialogText)
}

val uiState = viewModelState
    .map(ViewModelState::toUiState)
    .stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        viewModelState.value.toUiState(),
    )

There is an in-depth example in the compose samples from Google here.
